# Query - Excel - Dynamically change the custom color formats in Conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

**Intent:** Be able to dynamically change the ‘Custom format colors’ of a Conditional formatting rule based on HEX (or RGB) values stored in a different cell. This should allow future changing of background/foreground colors without having to manually update each conditional formatting rule individually.

**Background:** I have multiple records in my excel file with varying conditional formatting rules.

Have tried to explain it with an example (attached screenshot that shows 2 records) :

- **Score #1** [B3:B17] contains random values between 0 and 100
- **Score #2** [D3:D17] contains random values between 0 and 30

Both Score #1 & Score #2 contain three (3) conditional formatting brackets – Red, Yellow & Green (each set has different Lower & Upper bounds for conditional formatting; see ranges H3:I5 & H8:I10 respectively). Have used cell references in their conditional formatting rules to allow user to easily change these limits in the future.

The formatting of the three (3) types of brackets (Red, Yellow, Green) will be the same across all the datasets. Though, similar to the ability to change the limits, I would also like to give the future users an ability to easily change the formatting of the three brackets. Ideally, if one changes the HEX value from ranges G16:G18 and L16:L18, it should change the foreground (font color) and background (fill color) of these 3 formatting brackets (Red, Yellow & Green).

Is there any way to make this happen?

Please let me know if I could clarify any point... Thanks again for all your help!

Desktop Excel version 2301 (Build 16026.20200)

[Imgur Screenshot of Sample excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M3qT.jpg)

[Reddit Link to common query posted on r/excel](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/11hufby/query_excel_dynamically_change_the_custom_color/?sort=new)

[image]

I have tried to enter a formula to the RGB values in Custom color dialog box but these fields (see screenshot) do not seem to allow any cell reference.

Answer (score 0):

If an Excel worksheet's cell contains a hex code (e.g. #C00000) and you want to know what colour that is, then you can add a macro to the sheet like this:

1. ALT-F11 to edit a macro
2. Create a private "Worksheet" macro as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If (Left(ActiveCell.Text, 1) = "#" And Len(ActiveCell.Text) = 7) Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid$(ActiveCell.Text, 6, 2) & Mid$(ActiveCell.Text, 4, 2) & Mid$(ActiveCell.Text, 2, 2))
  End If
End Sub
```

3. Save the Excel workbook as "macro enabled".

Click or cursor through the cells containing the RGB value (e.g. #C00000) and the cell's contents will be set - see below for examples.  Note the MID$ functions reverse Excel's peculiar BGR to RGB format.

[image]